# Spark Streaming job how to send data on Kafka topic and saving it in Elastic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am working on a data analytic project, In which i am reading data from a CSV file, traversing that on a Kafka topic and using Spark Streaming to consume that Kafka topic data. All component I am using in a single project.

Now after consuming data with Spark Streaming I have to do some computation on it and I have to save the data into elastic search and i have to send that data on another topic. So I am doing these things (saving data into elastic and sending data to topic) from Spark Streaming.

Below is my code

```
@Component
public class RawEventSparkConsumer implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private ElasticSearchServiceImpl dataModelServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private EventKafkaProducer enrichEventKafkaProducer;

    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("rawTopic");

    public void sparkRawEventConsumer(JavaStreamingContext streamingContext) {

        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashedMap();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "group1");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", true);

        JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rawEventRDD = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(streamingContext,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));

        JavaDStream<String> dStream = rawEventRDD.map((x) -> x.value());

        JavaDStream<BaseDataModel> baseDataModelDStream = dStream.map(convertIntoBaseModel);
        baseDataModelDStream.foreachRDD(rdd1 -> {
            saveDataToElasticSearch(rdd1.collect());
        });

        JavaDStream<EnrichEventDataModel> enrichEventRdd = baseDataModelDStream.map(convertIntoEnrichModel);

        enrichEventRdd.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            System.out.println("Inside rawEventRDD.foreachRDD = = = " + rdd.count());
            sendEnrichEventToKafkaTopic(rdd.collect());
        });

        streamingContext.start();

        try {
            streamingContext.awaitTermination();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    static Function convertIntoBaseModel = new Function<String, BaseDataModel>() {

        @Override
        public BaseDataModel call(String record) throws Exception {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            BaseDataModel csvDataModel = mapper.readValue(record, BaseDataModel.class);
            return csvDataModel;
        }
    };

    static Function convertIntoEnrichModel = new Function<BaseDataModel, EnrichEventDataModel>() {

        @Override
        public EnrichEventDataModel call(BaseDataModel csvDataModel) throws Exception {

            EnrichEventDataModel enrichEventDataModel = new EnrichEventDataModel(csvDataModel);
            enrichEventDataModel.setEnrichedUserName("Enriched User");
            User user = new User();
            user.setU_email("Nitin.Tyagi");
            enrichEventDataModel.setUser(user);
            return enrichEventDataModel;
        }
    };

    private void sendEnrichEventToKafkaTopic(List<EnrichEventDataModel> enrichEventDataModels) {
        if (enrichEventKafkaProducer != null && enrichEventDataModels != null && enrichEventDataModels.size() > 0)
            try {
                enrichEventKafkaProducer.sendEnrichEvent(enrichEventDataModels);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    private void saveDataToElasticSearch(List<BaseDataModel> baseDataModelList) {
        if(!baseDataModelList.isEmpty())
            dataModelServiceImpl.saveAllBaseModel(baseDataModelList);
    }
}
```

Now I have few questions

1) Is my approach fine, i.e saving data in Elastic Search and sending it on topic from Spark Streaming?

2) I am using app components (Kafka , Spark Streaming) in a single project and there are multiple Spark Streaming classes. I am running these classes through CommandLineRunner in my local system. So now how can submit Spark Streaming as a spark job?

For Spark Submit do I need to create separate project with Spark Streaming classes?

Answer (score 0):

> Is my approach fine, i.e saving data in Elastic Search and sending it on topic from Spark Streaming?

I think I'd look into using ES-Hadoop Spark libraries. Looks like you've just used Elastic Java API directly (given that you're collecting RDD partitions)

While it might work, it's highly coupled... What happens when Elasticsearch is down for maintenance or otherwise highly latent? Does the whole application halt?

The alternative is to split the Kafka processing logic into its own deployment. This way, you could also just use Elasticsearch *Kafka Connect* process to load data from a topic without having to write that code yourself (the Connect API is probably already part of your running Kafka cluster)

> there are multiple Spark Streaming classes

Multiple main classes? That shouldn't be an issue. You need to give both a single JAR and a single class name to Spark submit. You can have multiple "entry points" / main methods within a single jar.

> how can submit Spark Streaming as a spark job?

I'm not sure I understand the problem. `spark-submit` works for streaming jobs

Note: CSV is one of the worst formats you can put into Kafka if you ever plan on changing your datatypes or their ordering, and you also expect the topic to be used by anyone but yourself. Even Elasticsearch would prefer you have json encoded payloads

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, Sure for the first point i will check Es-Spark library.  About the second point, as of now i have registered SparkStreaming job through CommandLineRunner in Spring. So when creating jar, should i create triggering these Spark Streaming job through main method? means should i remove commandlinerunner and put main() method in SparkStreamingJob. Please advice.

Comment: Sorry, not familar with how Spring works with Spark

Comment: ok. No Problem, Thanks. Can you give me some example link , how can we write and subscribe SparkStreaming in Java?